# Push notification to view iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, delegates, push, push-notification

I have got push notification working but the next thing I want to do is to open a relevant view when clicking on the notification.

In my `appDelegate.m` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, I have the following:

```
NSString *params=[[launchOptions objectForKey:@"UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] objectForKey:@"alertType"];

if ([params length] > 0 ) {//app launch when VIEW button of push notification clicked

    if (params == @"sc") {

         Alerts *alerts = [[Alerts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Alerts" bundle:nil];
         [[self navigationController] pushViewController:Alerts animated:YES];
         [Alerts release];
    } else {

    }
}
```

However, in this line: `[[self navigationController] pushViewController:Alerts animated:YES];`, a warning comes up saying **Method '-navigationController' not found (return type defaults to 'id')**.

How can I rectify this warning and am I right in trying to push the relevant view in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have a navigation controller in your app delegate as a property?

Comment: I don't think so. How can I make it as property as my `self.navigationController` works on other pages apart from the `appDelegate`. Thanks.

Comment: It works on other "pages" because they're not pages, but ViewControllers. All UIViewControllers automatically have a navigationController property, but not an appDelegate. For it to work, you have to manually create your navController in the app delegate, and add it to your view as AppAspect suggested you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `navigationController` may not be declared as a `@property`, so you can't use `[self navigationController]`. Just try `self.navigationController`, or even just `navigationController`, if that's its name in your `.h`.

Also, please don't compare strings with `==`. You have to do `if ([params isEqualToString:@"sc"])`. That compares the *contents* instead of the *address* of your string.

Comment: What do you mean by "if that's it's name in your .h"? I have tried `[self navigationController]`, `self.navigationController` and `navigationController` and it doesn't come up on the predictive list. Any ideas mate? Thanks.

Comment: Where and how is your navigationController declared? Could you post an excerpt from your `appDelegate.h` showing it?

Comment: In my .h, do I have to declare it like this: `UIView *navigationController`?

Comment: No, no, no... a navigationController is not even a UIView, it's a UINavigationController... Apparently you have not a good knowledge of the architecture of a UIKit application. You should take an in-depth look at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457 or consider a book that'll teach you the basics of UIKit, like http://www.apress.com/9781430230243

Comment: I know mate, but that was just an example. I have got an alertView to come up through that so seems good. Just not sure how to push a view from that now. Can I try to use `[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];`?

Comment: You can, but it won't work if you've created your navigationController incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add any navigation Controller to your window from the appdelegate method after setting the naviagationcontroller property.

```
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

You can then push the view as you required.